# I keep on getting the error name 'y_test' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, predict, train-test-split

I really need your help! I've written this code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def train_test_rmse(x,y):
    X = df_new[feature_cols]
    y = df_new['TOTAL CONSTRUCTION COST - EXCLUDING TAX']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2,random_state=123)
    linreg = LinearRegression()
    linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2,random_state=123)
    y_pred = linreg.predict(X_test)
    print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))  
    return np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
```

^ The code above runs correctly. But when I try to plot a scatter plot in the cell beneath:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(y_test, y_pred)
plt.xlabel('Actual Y')
plt.ylabel('Predicted Y')
plt.show()
```

I get the error "name 'y_test' is not defined". Please let me  know how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, i see that `y_test` is defined inside the `train_test_rmse` function, you need to initialize `y_test` outside this function.

your code should work fine with few changes as follows :

```
y_test = None

def train_test_rmse(x,y):
  
  global y_test
  
    X = df_new[feature_cols]
    y = df_new['TOTAL CONSTRUCTION COST - EXCLUDING TAX']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2,random_state=123)
```

Comment: Hi Anand, thank you very much for your response. But unfortunately, now I've added in this code nothing is showing up on the scatter plot. It is blank. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you share the script itself, I imagine, this could be due to execution order. Did you try clearing the whole notebook and run all cells?

Comment: Hi Anand, I don't think I'll be able to share the entire script sadly as it contains confidential data. But I did clear the entire notebook and ran all cells and it came up with the error "name 'y_pred' is not defined" instead. So I decided to create an entire new notebook altogether that only included 4 cells (1. importing the libraries. 2. creating the dataframe 3&4. the code in my original post with your corrections) and it still showed an empty scatter plot. So I really don't know what could be wrong

Comment: can you check the values of y_test and y_pred before running the scatter plot ? i suspect either one of them is causing this issue.